# ASP.NET MVC async Controller doesn't Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

Hello I have the problem
when I try to call a function  **GetDataById** method controller doesn't work
I try to debug but after calling method **GetDataById** I can't go  any further

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateEmployee(RegisterModel model)
    {


        var d = new DistrictService();
        var r = new RegionService();
        var region = r.GetDataById(model.RegionId);
        var district = d.GetDataById(model.DistrictId);


        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            FullName = model.FullName,
            Email = model.Email,
            District = district,
            Region = null,
            Address = model.Address
        };

        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var resOfAddRoleToUser = userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.Role);
            await SignIn(user);
        }

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }            
    }
```

but program enter in  GetDataById method

Comment: There needs to be a little more explanation here. For starters, what is `DistrictService` and `RegionService` ?

Comment: When you say it doesnt work, do you get any exceptions thrown? If you aren't seeing any exception, go to your exception settings and enable all CLR exceptions to be caught (check the box)

Comment: I don't have any exceptions that's the problem, two classes which will work with db though EF, get all data, get data by ID and so on

Comment: What I like to do in my Controllers if i have any weird behaviours: Build a try/catch around it and look if it jumps into the catch block. then you can easily get the errormessage if there's any

Comment: Please show us your GetDataById() method

Comment: `public Region GetDataById(int id)`
        {
            return _ctx.Regions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }

Comment: Make sure `GetDataById` does not call `Wait` on some `Task`. This usually cause deadlock.

Comment: There is a error being thrown, you exception settings aren't set to pick it up, please see previous comment